# The class variable is undefined in class method

Tags: php, class, methods

Just look at the simple code below. The server tells me the error that `wheel_count` in the function `car_detail()` is not defined. So, Why should it be like this?

Can you help me?

```
<?php 

class cars {

    var $wheel_count = 4;
    var $door_count = 4;

    function car_detail() {
        return $this->$wheel_count;
    }

}

$bmw = new cars();
echo $bmw->car_detail();

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$this->wheel_count` to access the property :)

Note that you had an extra "$".

In case that you have properties declared as `static`, then you'd access them using "$":

```
static $something = 'blah';

function getSomething()
{
    return self::$something;
}
```

...or 'outside' the class:

```
$something = MyClass::$something;
```

Also, consider using a bit more advanced code editor / IDE that would let you know that you have invalid code as soon as you type it.

Comment: Thank you very very much. Actually I have phstorm and zen studio, but i don't like them because I like sublime text better. Thank you again!